# React-table custom sort only works in the ascending direction when using structured data and default sort with 'sorted' prop

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-table

I'm using react-table with structured data and a default sort using the 'sorted' prop and my custom sort only sorts in the ascending direction.

Please see a demo of this issue here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-table-default-sorting-vxe3e

Note that this is different from the more basic demos as the data is *structured* such that multiple data points can be displayed in each cell. Here I put the 'firstName' and 'lastName' data points inside another object called 'name' so they could conceivably both be displayed in the same cell.

How can I get my custom sort to work in both the ascending and descending directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out using the 'sorted' prop is not the proper approach here. I changed this to 'defaultSorted' and it started working in both directions.